# Compare strings by natural order but ignoring string's prefix

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream, comparator

I am struggling to sort a stream of strings (or list, if you prefer) in natural order ignoring a prefix.
The prefix begins always with *let* and could be followed by any numbers (example, let12 or let3021)

Sample input:

```
let3 art zero
let2 own kit dig
let1 art can
```

Sample desired output:

```
let1 art can
let3 art zero
let2 own kit dig
```

So a simple idea that I have tried is to do the following:

```
list.stream().sorted();
```

But the numbers get in the way, producing the following output:

```
let1 art can
let2 own kit dig
let3 art zero
```

How can achieve this result in a simple way? The ideal solution would be a Comparator, or anything that I can use in a stream flow.

Note: my attempt to use the Comparator failed due the fact that the prefix could be of any length.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're answering your own question: With a comparator.

```
Comparator<String> marcosPrefixIgnoringComparison =
    (a, b) -> a.substring(4).compareTo(b.substring(4));
```

That's assuming that the prefix is defined as 'the first 4 characters'. If it's more 'The string `let`, and then any number of digits', you'd have to do something else. Possibly regexes:

```
Comparator<String> marcosPrefixIgnoringComparison =
    (a, b) -> a.replaceFirst("^let\\d+\\s+", "").compareTo(
      b.replaceFirst("^let\\d+\\s+", ""));
```

your question is not particularly clear about what 'prefix' means, here.

Comment: Hi,
my bad, I have updated the question with more details about the prefix.
My attempt with the comparator failed because the prefix could be of any length.
I know really little about regex, I will dive deeper into your second answer and let you know.
Thank you for your time

Comment: @Marco You could also use the static methods from `Comparator` to transform the strings prior to comparison. The argument to the `comparing` method is a `Function` transforming a string. This function is applied to both strings subject to the comparison. For example, `Comparator.comparing(str -> str.replaceFirst("^let\\d+\\s+", ""))` will yield the same result as `marcosPrefixIgnoringComparison` above.

Comment: …and if you care for performance, you will compile the regex to a `Pattern` object once and keep it, to avoid parsing this nontrivial regex two times on every comparison.

Comment: Thank you Mc Emperor, that's even more concise and clean.
That's good to know, Holger, thank you!